# How do I disable Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

I use GNOME Classic. There is no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> shortcut in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

[image]

It should be configured somewhere else. But where?

Answer (score 72):

Remove the default keybinding using the following commands

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']"
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"
```

Comment: Using gnome-shell on Arch, and this is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: Had to do this in order to use this shortcut for other apps in ubuntu 18.04. Note that in ubuntu 18.04 (today 2018-05-22) there is no left or right workspace by default and there is no way to configure this shortcut via graphical settings

Comment: On recent gnome-shell is not possible to have left and right workspaces but keybinding is still active (and clashing with Intellij IDEA defaults).

Comment: If you prefer a GUI editor, you can run `dconf-editor` instead of the above `gsettings` commands.  In the editor, navigate to the same path (`/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`).

Comment: gsettings still works on ubuntu 18.04, but it requires to restart gnome-shell to apply the new bindings (`Alt+F2`, `r`, `<enter>`)

Answer (score 19):

In my system, those configs are available in System Settings -> Keyboard. Please double-check.

[image]

If those aren't available, you can try add them with `gconf-editor`. If you use Metacity, simply go to `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings` and add the corresponding values:

[image]

If you use Compiz, you can follow the steps provided by @ams

Comment: I don't have these items, see my [screenshot](http://dump.geevee.ru/shortcuts.png)

Comment: updated, i hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

Finally, in Ubuntu 22/04 this can be disabled using `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `View and Customize Shortcuts` -> `Navigation`. In there, find `Move to workspace on the left` and `Move to workspace on the right`, click on each entry and re-assign `Super+Page Up` and `Super+Page Down` respectively. This will disable any other assigned shortcuts.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, following `Customize Shortcuts` and set `Move to workspace to left` to `Super+Page up`, but this does not disable `Ctrl+Shift+Left` to be working at the same time... Any idea how I can disable it?

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 22.10. Finally using it in PHP Storm again. Although I had to assign it there, as Navigate back is assigned to Shift Alt Left on Linux and Ctrl Alt Left on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

CompizConfig Setting Manager (it's not installed by default though).

Then go to "Desktop Wall Plugin", and it's on the "Bindings" tab.

*That's assuming you are using Unity (full 3D), or (edit) Gnome with effects enabled.*

Comment: No, I'm not using Unity, I am using GNOME Classic.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a few words I meant to type .... I'll correct it above.

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

open gconf-editor.

Go to /apps/metacity/global keybindings and change the values according to my screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu 22:

whenever i was pressing ctrl alt left/right my workspace would move.

However, in the keyboards settings I did not have such a shortcut set but i had one for each:

a. Move workspace on the left ; shortcut: ctrl + alt + up (wtf)

b.Move workspace on the right: ctrl + alt + down (wtf again)

when i disabled the above two ctrl+alt+left/right stopped working as well.

.. quite interesting one might add ...

Comment: Thanks! This works! I don't know why this is so weird now.