# Disable Alt+Left Arrow Key "shortcut"

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.10

On 18.10, it seems that

```
Alt+LeftArrowKey
```

flashes a black screen then asks me to log back in to my session, which resumes as it was.

I am not sure why this is something you would want to do.  On my keyboard, this is so close to `Ctrl+Alt+PageUp/Down` and causes me to mistakenly have to log back into my session frequently.  I would like to disable this keybinding.

In older Ubuntus, this setting was [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-disable-ctrlaltleft-right).  However, in the new Settings > Keyboard, I can't seem to identify what this is attempting to shortcut to to set it to null.

Comment: Apparently reported here https://askubuntu.com/questions/893964/altleft-key-locks-the-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alt+Left key locks the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893964/altleft-key-locks-the-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by rebooting as suggested in the link to the comment.

Comment: Thank you for shareing.  Next time, please flag the question as a duplicate.  **;-)**